# Equivariant (co)homology of flag manifolds, convolution algebra and nil hecke algebra?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, equivariant-cohomology

For a complex reductive group $G$ and its Borel subgroup $B$, it seems to be well-known that the equivariant homology group $H^G_*(G/B\times G/B)$ forms a nil-Heck algebra
$$NH=\Bbbk[y_i,\partial_{j}]_{{1\leq i\leq n}\atop{1\leq j\leq n-1}}\big/\left<\begin{array}{c}
\partial_i\partial_{i+1}\partial_i=\partial_{i+1}\partial_{i}\partial_{i+1}\\
\partial_{i}\partial_j=\partial_j\partial_i, |i-j|\geq 2\\
\partial_i^2=0\end{array},\quad
\begin{array}{c}y_j\partial_j=\partial_j y_{j+1}\\
y_{j+1}\partial_j=\partial_j y_{j}\\
y_j\partial_i=\partial_iy_j, |i-j|\geq 2
\end{array}\right>$$
under convolution with the Schubert cells $X_w$ corresponding to the symbol $\partial_w$. Besides, its action over the equivariant cohomology group $H_G^*(G/B)=H_T(pt)=\Bbbk[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is the Demazure operator.

But I did not find any reference for this fact even for the definition of convolution. I only saw the usual homology (Borel--Moore homology) version and the K-theory version in *Representation Theory and Complex Geometry* by Neil ChrissVictor Ginzburg. Besides, they refer without proofs. Maybe it can be defined by sheaf theory, but then how to compute with the Schubert cells? Since $H_G(G/B\times G/B)=H_T(G/T)$, it has Schubert cells.

In the cohomology case, we can define the convolution in a proper way to be
$$H^*_G(B\times A)\times H^*_G(C\times B)\stackrel{p_1^*\otimes p_3^*}\longrightarrow H_G^*(C\times B\times A)\otimes H_G^*(C\times B\times A)\stackrel{\smile}\longrightarrow H_G^*(C\times B\times A)\stackrel{(p_2)_*}\longrightarrow H_G^*(C\times A)$$
The last map is the Gysin push forward when $B$ is smooth compact. The problem of homology is that there is no intersection product for $EG\times_G C\times B\times A$ since it is infinite dimensional. Moreover when I compute the convolution over equivariant cohomology, it does not give the a proper isomorphism $H_G^*(G/B\times G/B)\to NH$.

My question is, are there any references for the fact that $H^G_*(G/B\times G/B)\cong NH$ under convolution and references for the definition of convolution algebra in equivariant homology? Further I also wonder if there is an isomorphism from cohomology to $NH$?

Answer (score 3):

I did more computation recently, and I got what I desired.

Firstly, to be exact, it should be the cohomology group rather than homology group, and presentation in the question is wrong, it should be
$$\Bbbk\left<X_i,\partial_j\right>_{{1\leq i\leq n}\atop{1\leq j\leq n-1}}\bigg/
\left<\begin{array}{c}
\partial_i\partial_{i-1}\partial_i=\partial_{i-1}\partial_i\partial_{i-1},\\
|i-j|\geq 2, \quad \partial_i\partial_j=\partial_j\partial_i,\\
\partial_i^2=0. \end{array}\begin{array}{c}
X_iX_j=X_jX_i,\\
\partial_iX_j-X_{s_i(j)}\partial_i\\
=\delta_{i,j}-\delta_{i+1,j}.
\end{array}\right>$$
I was mislead by Kumar's definition (Kac-Moody Groups, their Flag Variety and Representation Theory) of Nil-Hecke ring and the definition of convolution in homology.

- To prove this, one can first do it in nonequivairant case, the $G$-orbits of $G/B\times G/B$ are one-to-one correspondent to $B$-orbit of $G/B$, i.e. Schubert cells.
- The Poincar'e duality of each, say $\partial_w$, with respect to the Schuber cell $BwB/B$, acts on $H^*(G/B)$ by the Demazure operator $\partial_w$. To check this, it suffices to do the intersection product, where they all intersects transversally.
- The $X_i=X_i\partial_e$, where $H^*(G/B)$ acts on $H^*(G/B\times G/B)$ by the first projection acts on $H^*(G/B)$ by left multiplication $X_i$.
- Now relation is easy to check, by a standard topological argument, it is an isomorphism (for example, Harish–Leray). Actually, $H^*(G/B\times G/B)$ is actually the subalgebra generated by left mutiplications and Demazure operators in $\operatorname{End}_{\Bbbk}(H^*(G/B))$.
- To deal with equivariant case, we first do it in $T$-equivariant case, it is harmless since $H_G^*(X)\to H_T^*(X)$ is always injective ($\operatorname{char} \Bbbk=0$).
- There no longer exists Poincar'e duality, but the pairing of cells also gives a well-defined cohomology class. The computation of the result of paring of cells in nonequivariant case can be directly move to equivariant case. As a result, so it also acts as Demazure operator.
- The rest is completely the same to nonequivariant case. Actually, $H_G^*(G/B\times G/B)$ is actually the subalgebra generated by left mutiplications and Demazure operators in $\operatorname{End}_{H_G^*(pt)}(H^*(G/B))$. The actions are all $H_G^*(pt)$ map by the associativity of convolution
  $$H_G^*(G/B\times G/B)\stackrel{\displaystyle\curvearrowright}{\phantom{\square}}
    H_G^*(G/B\times pt)\stackrel{\displaystyle\curvearrowleft}{\phantom{\square}} H_G^*(pt\times pt). $$

---

The last two points are wrong. The real reason is, over characteristic zero case, $H_G(G/B)$ is known to be free of rank $\dim H(G/B)$ over $H_G(pt)$. So bthe convolution algebra is eaxctly of rank $\dim H(G/B)^2$ over $H_G(pt)$. This is the main point.

Comment: You should edit any corrections into your question.